# LINQ: Joining List<object> and dataset on a comma separated value field?

Tags: linq, csv

I am using C# and LINQ and trying to combine two sets of data. The first is a List of a specific type, lets call this Status (List) which is just a class with a bunch of properties one of which includes a comma separated value list of accounts. This is queried from the application database using a stored procedure so I have some flexability as to what is displayed here

For example:

```
class Status
{
   ...
   public string Accounts {get; set;} (ie. "abcde, qwerty, asdfg")
   public string Managers {get; set;}
   ...
}
```

The rest of the properties are irrelevant as this is the only field I am joining on.

The second "Accounts" data set is from a web service which I am calling to get a list of "Accounts" and the people associated with each account.

For example:

```
Account    Manager                 SomeData   MoreFields     ...
-------    -------------------     --------   ----------     ---
abcde      Bob Marley              Data       MoreData       ...
qwerty     Fred Flinstone          Data       MoreData       ...
```

So bascially I need to Create a list of Status objects with a CSV list of Manager(s) from the Accounts dataset in the Managers property of Status. Problem is I have no control over what is retruend in this dataset as it is a third party application. So I need to find some way to do this without modifying the "Accounts" data. Unless I do something in memory after getting the dataset from the web service.

I hope this makes sense and I thank you in advance!

Comment: Your "accounts" should be a `HashSet<string>` or some other type of collection rather than a string of comma separated values.

Comment: The problem here is that due to limitations on how we are allowed to query the database. I HAVE to use stored procedures. So I cant really return anything for the "Accounts" field in Status, except some kind of concatenated string of accounts. Unless I query each status individually and populate some collection or hashset of accounts. I feel like I am missing something blatantly obvious here.

Comment: Even if that property is set from the database, you could have a read-only property that presents the same data as a collection. `public ICollection AccountCollection { get { return Accounts.Split(',').ToList(); } }` - note that's just example.  It would be better to use a private backing field and use the setter on `Accounts` to populate it.  Depending on how you are going to use it a `HashSet<string>` could be the most effective option, assuming you're going to want to do a significant number of "membership" lookups doing the join.

Answer (score 0):

What is this "dataset" of which you speak? I don't care where it come from -- I just care what kind of object it is in C#.

I'm going to assume that it's an ICollection, called "accounts"

Next, I'm going to assume that Managers  is a CVS list much like Accounts.

Further, I'm only going to create one status object instead of a "list" of them, since you never say what separates one status from another.

```
var status = new Status();
status.Accounts = string.Join( ", ", from k in accounts select k.Account);
status.Managers = string.Join( ", ", from k in accounts select k.Manager);
```

Comment: Accounts is literally a DataSet. Firstly upon querying Status the only field that is populated is the accounts field with the CSV data (ie. "abcde, qwerty, asdfg"). The Accounts DataSet is just a huge list of accounts (strings), so basically I need to find all Managers in the Accounts dataset by their account name (Account), and populate the Managers field in Status with another CSV list of the actual managers names. Does that make sense? There are many ways I can do this, for example simply enumerating Status messages and querying each one, but there are 60k records so this is slow.